# There is a way to do a PRE_DELETE event for IResources like IFolders?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to perform a clean up task before a folder get's deleted, currently I tried adding a IResourceChangeListener with the IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_DELETE event, however this just gets triggered when a project gets deleted.

Also tied IResourceDelta but this only notifies IResourceDelta.CHANGED and doesn't block the thread to perform some tasks before the IFolder gets deleted, without mentioning that the CHANGED event is triggered for creation and deletion without having a way to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.deleteParticipants` extension point to define a 'delete refactoring participant'. This will be called during the delete process and can define actions to be taken during the delete.

The delete participant is a class which extends `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.DeleteParticipant`.

For more details see the Platform Plug-in Developer Guide in the Eclipse Help.